# How to delete one specific modifier from all selected objects, but keep the other modifiers on them

Tags: modifiers

Hi I have these objects in a scene, of which some only have a Build modifer, and others may have a Build modifier and other modifiers (Bevel, etc..)

I would like to remove the Build modifier from all of these objects, but for those objects that have other modifiers preferrably the other modifiers are kept.

If this is not workable, please alternatively advise how to remove all modifiers from all selected objects instead.

Thanks in advance!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
from bpy import data as D

for ob in D.objects:
    for mod in ob.modifiers[:]:
        if mod.type == 'BUILD':
            ob.modifiers.remove(mod)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you